# How can I access a ruby object's method by using a hash syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, methods, accessor

I am working on Ruby on Rails, and I want to create a helper method for my view. I must pass an active record object, a *symbol* variable and a title to the method.

The objective of this method is to take the data, create some < strong > and < p > tags to put the title and the object attribute on the database (by accessing with the symbol variable) and  get a nice HTML bit of code to put on my view.

Everything works fine, except when I need to display some of the object's attribute (like a datetime attribute, or a boolean value) which I need to *call a specific object's method*. For example, get the status of the user If he has confirmed his email, return string "Confirmed", if not, return string "Unconfirmed".

- Helper code

```
module UsersHelper
    def user_show_field(user, column, title=nil)
        title ||= column.titleize
        return "<p><strong>#{title}</strong>: #{user[column]}</p>".html_safe
    end
end
```

- View code

```
<%= user_show_field(@user, :city, "City") %>
```

In the example above, there will be no problem, because :city is a attribute from the user. So the helper method will attempt to make the call

```
@user[:city]
```

However, if I want to get the status of my user, I'll need to call the *get_status method* of my user:

```
@user[:get_status]
```

This Will return nil, because :get_status is not a attribute on the database of my user model: it is a method defined on my app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    def get_status
        return registered ? "Email confirmed" : "Unconfirmed user"
    end

end
```

How can I add some code to my user model, so I can use the helper with both the attributes on the database or model's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke methods with a symbol or a string using `send` (note that you can even call private methods with `send`, you can use `public_send` instead).

```
@user.send(:get_status)
```

If your method requires parameters, just add the separated by comma:

```
@user.send(:another_method, param1, param2)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send

Comment: Thanks, this has got the job done. How it is called this way of calling methods on ruby? To search more on google? lambda methods?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 is ancient and APIDock has been abandoned, you'd be better off linking to https://ruby-doc.org

Comment: @Karl, you can read about reflection and meta programming, check this example on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Ruby

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest instead of send all field, using one string is more simple, something like this below

```
module UsersHelper
  def user_show_field(user_data, title=nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      return "<p><strong>#{title}</strong>: #{user_data}</p>".html_safe
  end
end
```

here you can call from your view, without change your model

```
   <%= user_show_field(@user.city, "City") %>
   <%= user_show_field(@user.get_status, "Status") %>
```

Comment: Sometimes simple is better than complex, thanks. However, I've always had some curiosity about how to get these kind of things done: I've always look at the models and the "before_validation :get_status" kind of thing, and I was wondering how to implement it.This was the opportunity to learn it.